# inline assembly constraint for value that might be overwritten

Tags: assembly, arm, inline-assembly

I'm debugging some assembly code, and after reading some documentation, I'm not sure I understand constraints 100%.  I was wondering if someone could set me straight.  If I have the following code (arm32):

```
int foo(int in1, int *ptr1) {
    int out1=123;

    asm volatile (
        "   cmp     %[in1],  #0;"
        "   bne     1b;"
        "   dmb;"
        "   mov     %[out1], #0;"
        "1: strex   %[in1], [%[ptr1]];"
        : [out1]"=r", [ptr1]"+r"(ptr1),
        : [in1]"r"(in1),
        : "memory" );

    return out1;
}
```

I'm unclear of a few things:   First, I mark `out1` as being an output, but it is only an output if `in1` is zero.  I'm worried that `=r` constraint is being interpreted as 'this value is *always* set', telling the optimizer that any previous value is irrelevant.  Of course, I'm not sure how I would write a constraint for something that *might* change...

I'm also concerned with `ptr1`.   The pointer itself is not actually set, but what it points to is.   I'm wondering if this should have a read constraint, and wondering if there's a proper way to set this constraint.

Note, I am using this code on multiple compilers (gcc, and clang, and various versions of each), so I'd like to avoid any assumptions about specific optimizers.

Comment: "always set" and "maybe set" equivalently means "don't rely on previous contents" which is what the compiler only cares about. You, on the other hand, should know not to use the result if it's not set. As for the other question, indeed `ptr1` does not need to be read-write. The `"memory"` clobber takes care of writing to the pointed value (even if that's a little overkill). You could probably split this code so that only `dmb` and `strex` are assembly.

Comment: The posted code is a simplified example.    If `out1` is not set, I want the old value to carry through (so the assembly conditionally sets a value), so what would be the constraint?   Would it be `+r`?

Comment: What's worse is that your `out1` and `in1` may overlap. Yes, `+r` should work for that case.

Comment: Sorry, you mentioned that `"memory"` is overkill -- is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Probably just an unused output operand `"=m" (*ptr1)`

Comment: What you really want to be doing is using single instruction asm statements for DMB and STREX and let the compiler handle the rest.  Or better yet use compiler intrinsics where available.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's correct, `"=r"` means write-only.  The register is dead on input.  The compiler won't bother putting anything specific in the selected register before the asm, because it's going to be overwritten.  The compiler will optimize like if you wrote `out1 = asm_result;` outside inline asm.

`"+r"` is an input/output operand.  If it *might* be modified, you need the compiler to assume that it always has been.

Look at the compiler-generated asm for the function, e.g. on the Godbolt compiler explorer.  (https://godbolt.org/).  You can see what code the compiler generates around your inline asm, including after inlining into another function.

---

> I'm also concerned with `ptr1`. The pointer itself is not actually set, but what it points to is.

Yes, you are right to be concerned.  `"+r"(ptr1)` tells the compiler the pointer value is modified, but does *not* imply that the pointed-to value is modified.  The `"memory"` clobber is a heavy way to do that, or as Jester says, you should just use an `"=m"(*ptr1)` constraint instead to let the compiler pick an addressing mode, and tell it that the pointed-to memory is unconditionally written.

---

### Or better, https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/DontUseInlineAsm

Does STREX even make sense without a preceding LDREX?  I don't think so, but if I'm wrong then you only need inline asm for that one instruction, because ARM compilers just use plain `str` even for atomic stores.

If this function does the 2nd half of a LL/SC, then that's pretty weird.

Are you sure you can't do what you want with a built-in `__atomic_store(ptr1, value, __ATOMIC_RELAXED)` + optional barrier, or a C11 `atomic_store_explicit`?

```
#include <stdatomic.h>
int foo(int in1, int *ptr1) {
    int out1=123;

    if (in1 != 0) {
        out1 = 0;
        //asm("dmb" ::: "memory");
        atomic_thread_fence(memory_order_release);  // make the following stores release-stores wrt. earlier operations
    }
    atomic_store_explicit((_Atomic int*)ptr1, in1, memory_order_relaxed);
    return out1;
}
```

Compiles with gcc6.3, [on the Godbolt compiler explorer](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,source:'%23include+%3Cstdatomic.h%3E%0Aint+foo(int+in1,+int+*ptr1)+%7B%0A++++int+out1%3D123%3B%0A%0A++++if+(in1+!!%3D+0)+%7B%0A++++++++out1+%3D+0%3B%0A++++++++//asm(%22dmb%22+:::+%22memory%22)%3B%0A++++++++atomic_thread_fence(memory_order_release)%3B%0A++++%7D%0A++++atomic_store_explicit((_Atomic+int*)ptr1,+in1,+memory_order_relaxed)%3B%0A++++return+out1%3B%0A%7D%0A'),l:'5',n:'0',o:'C%2B%2B+source+%231',t:'0')),k:35.13713057457777,l:'4',m:100,n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0'),(g:!((g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:armg630,filters:(b:'0',binary:'1',commentOnly:'0',demangle:'0',directives:'0',execute:'1',intel:'0',trim:'1'),lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:'-xc+-O3+-Wall++-mcpu%3Dcortex-a53',source:1),l:'5',n:'0',o:'ARM+gcc+6.3.0+(linux)+(Editor+%231,+Compiler+%231)+C%2B%2B',t:'0')),k:23.491068847669467,l:'4',m:75.07507507507508,n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0'),(g:!((h:output,i:(compiler:1,editor:1,wrap:'1'),l:'5',n:'0',o:'%231+with+ARM+gcc+6.3.0+(linux)',t:'0')),header:(),l:'4',m:24.92492492492493,n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0')),k:35.99853310883532,l:'3',n:'0',o:'',t:'0'),(g:!((g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:clang600,filters:(b:'0',binary:'1',commentOnly:'0',demangle:'0',directives:'0',execute:'1',intel:'0',trim:'1'),lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:'-xc+-O3+-Wall+-target+arm-linux-gnu+-mcpu%3Dcortex-m4',source:1),l:'5',n:'0',o:'x86-64+clang+6.0.0+(Editor+%231,+Compiler+%232)+C%2B%2B',t:'0')),header:(),k:28.864336316586915,l:'4',m:63.56356356356356,n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0'),(g:!((h:output,i:(compiler:2,editor:1,wrap:'1'),l:'5',n:'0',o:'%232+with+x86-64+clang+6.0.0',t:'0')),header:(),l:'4',m:36.43643643643644,n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0')),k:28.864336316586915,l:'3',n:'0',o:'',t:'0')),l:'2',n:'0',o:'',t:'0')),version:4):

```
@ gcc6.3 -O3 -mcpu=cortex-a53  (ARM mode)
foo:
        subs    r3, r0, #0    @ copy in1 and set flags from it at the same time
        moveq   r0, #123      @ missed-optimization: since we still branch, no point hoisting this out of the if with predication
        bne     .L5
        str     r3, [r1]      @ if()-not-taken path
        bx      lr
.L5:
        dmb     ish           @ if()-taken path
        mov     r0, #0        @ makes the moveq doubly silly, because we do it again inside the branch.
        str     r3, [r1]
        bx      lr          @ out1 return value in r0
```

So it runs the same instructions as your implementation (except str instead of strex), but it branches differently, using tail duplication and probably saves instructions overall (with maybe larger code-size but lower *dynamic* instruction count, because we used `-O3`.)  With `-Os`, we get very compact asm that's more like your inline-asm (jumping over a mov and a `dmb`).

Clang makes the whole thing branchless, using an `itte` (in thumb mode) to predicate the `dmbne sy`.  (See its output on Godbolt.)

---

**Note that a separate barrier is typically less efficient if you want to port this to AArch64**.  You want the compiler to be able to use AArch64's [`stlr`](http://www.keil.com/support/man/docs/armclang_asm/armclang_asm_pge1427897421621.htm) release store (even though it's a sequential-release, not a weaker plain release).  `dmb ish` is a full memory barrier.   Also, 32-bit code for ARMv8 can use [`stl`](http://www.keil.com/support/man/docs/armclang_asm/armclang_asm_pge1429113453813.htm).

Note that a full `dmb` will order *other* later stores wrt. earlier stores, so this isn't exactly equivalent on AArch64 (or 32-bit with ARMv8 instructions available), where compiler-generated code doesn't use a `dmb`.

**This version compiles to pretty nice asm for all architectures:** One missed-optimization I see is that compilers don't manage to separate the `dmb` from the `str`, leaving one common `str` after a conditional `dmb`.  (For cases where they have to use `dmb`).

```
// recommended version
int foo_ifelse(int in1, int *ptr1) {
    int out1=123;
    if (in1 != 0) {
        out1 = 0;
        atomic_store_explicit((_Atomic int*)ptr1, in1, memory_order_release);
    } else {
        atomic_store_explicit((_Atomic int*)ptr1, in1, memory_order_relaxed);
    }
    return out1;
}
```

AArch64 gcc6.3 -O3 output ([Godbolt compiler explorer](https://godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5TKALEBjA9gEwKYFFMCWALugE4A0BIEAViAIzkA2AhgHaioCkATAEK8%2B5AM7oArqVTYQAcl4BmAm1RMxOANRd5AYWFFMLEgFsCqAHRItuLgAYAgkqLqAZunQRH6pYy9snAKgAHIlJ6AEpNAHYBe3U43ydxInotABF6HnktGLtbO3ivZ3UPNnp1MDA09RsIrmi8goKksqqbbIbGuIB6LpZhIwheHkwjACMh9RApzR4eI2wjMgBPIbD22M71Q3QTVAB9IiRSbBZMPedsZWwIecXSJb2yHFI946YT4Ww1%2BT5urvU2OhEsECEYWEwOnE6qlIVtjKY9noyNg9tgAB6BJimYhQPZ2eGoBL%2BMLBULkXw%2BW7LR6kZ6vbCsNHYTDfHIFY5ECRsdTNda5SIw%2Bx5HrqY4YIzzNg4TDqABu2FIwgI6DYeU8rnQewIFyYnxKTm85M8QRC4SibPinl58nSmT5BW1xW85UqNuqtXqG06zU0braP1hBW2u0RJGOqIxWNQOIgeIJRJJpqNpXJVPuNLpbw%2BX3t8Wh6gZn3NgfiwYRSPD6Mx2KIuPxO1MCdJPkN6jTDyeCvpjOZrNh0NhHK5PLEyT5A6F9hFmBVYBkThn6kOBGE5OAqEJNDEenUemOHEOlzlLFIBBYo3eAFpO6Ql%2Bhd9gAI57VB6YX/QFObDy7lbneH3cQhVYBsB3dAigAwJ0GEJUL2wHlaQVYQXDIJckEMdRUD6bAzDVPwUM1WUTzPOCMwVfUKWTAJmw9C04itUcUhtDIsgDL02wWakbwQ55fVSDi7g7RCXjeFgmUwcd2MdEoygqVpaJLOIfVaXNvWEviBK44Tu2zVSokFfJ4hFABlAAZAB5AB1dQ7AAOX4gBJWzcAAMRchztAc3BbIAFXUAB3YgkHUddUHJFR2GAdRCD3AhRlHUCvESeVbwA0ZSHYVBLHYst9grFEqyjGM4wbQlHGJZtkx8G8%2B3YodSG5a0cgnOwZDCZhZAAVhkcg2FkGwevQWRtEEQRd3ESR4IUegeqIfq2vagBrEAABYbDMSJ6EiHgbBWzr6HoeQeAANkiFaOpkFaeqMEBjs6sx5Dux7Oue17jt6%2BbyCGmQeuEEAbHIOaZAG9q4FgFBxUCAh3goKgIEh6GFRAYAAA4eHIZxoaIJDqFGT7RiUE8llkGbyHFSUiHMtgmGJ4GepwMEOHeT7CDFIgCHlP66fIdFsFQBKSZ6xwGU%2BkJQUF9rWA4NBRv4Zg4r%2ByB2vQEEVS5y80UJS9zPkdRL0s8EmF%2BiapAYSWup6vrue%2BtEUeOy9jpWkKN3UFGzB4Yp8GIVDpvJbQdihmGZnkFaIhG/hBFm%2BawnapATmeahzcu66QBDsxjpDjOVqznP5A%2B63ZF%2B/7AejpbVvoMxOoATke46UZequ0eOjJ3qYWR5Etz7vqjunQcQCAIYDxHYeoBGYZAE8jGADOAcxphscVXH8cJ%2B5BbJnYKapmmWYWSLme51m%2BfZznPt5/nsbX4W2%2B5sWbpkGbJcimWI7lrFRkViBldVth1c1vXzOQvrQ2cRLxGFQIEMQaQMCkGxmiUBTtQGHDEGMY2EhTbhAut1fOA0vqyDsAAJQALLO0JMdB6ZgbDFCxGwMQaIIgQC9mGYOPh/ZGEDgqZhYdZZ8B7iDMuPA3aO32itEOnUVqNyrmdC6V1yA3XoDYAGVscHdxEMXIGINyBgwQPAAeaAh4w0oKPfRSNJ6O2nvIWeWMcYQDxtzAmbAiZr3JpcSm1NaY4IZnvaQB8CBsw5qBU%2BTJz7eNJlfUWp474P2YE/bgL8hBvw/l/dmatZAay1jrPWBsmBGxECbaQGDr5YKUYNPBRDHYkPUGQ%2BQFCqFKFofQxhPtMgsOMbeBQPAuFxN4QtcgcdThI0/uQZaAizB2xEY9eQ9A7p2yrvQTq0iU4rUiBtJZZ1IhrI2fM4puCfqqIBuotqmj%2B6DzYcPQx8NWloCltPBRGMrGLxscvBxq9749WcX4Le7j6a7yZt4jxvij7%2BK5jgs%2BAtXmUD8CLG%2BESJbROlrEgQr8FbwCScqH%2BqS/7a11kA7JesiAnhAk4Sel52CYFIOgAgmBLzABoXrMBECoFkFgSSuZqDJpm0wZ3AuMhbb23KRFDglSKE1IYYQJhvt1CsPYW0zI8hOmIp4SXXuScZE3U6jwd26qeBap1bMLZXdC57KVXwoZIAeBVw2s3egKMUYKP2ijFa9BzrXw7tgkpuyDkxwujwLlyjDWevailJUKpVpAA%3D%3D%3D)):

```
foo_ifelse:
    cbnz    w0, .L9       @ compare-and-branch-non-zero
    str     wzr, [x1]     @ plain (relaxed) store
    mov     w0, 123
    ret
.L9:
    stlr    w0, [x1]      @ release-store
    mov     w0, 0
    ret
```

You *could* make the `order` parameter a variable as a way to simplify your source, but gcc does a very bad job with it.  (clang turns it back into a branch).  GCC strengthens it to seq_cst, even though the only 2 options in this case are relaxed and release.

```
// don't do this, gcc just strengthen variable-order to seq_cst
int foo_variable_order(int in1, int *ptr1) {
    int out1=123;
    memory_order order = memory_order_relaxed;

    if (in1 != 0) {
        out1 = 0;
        order = memory_order_release;
    }
    // SLOW AND INEFFICIENT with gcc
    // but clang distributes it over the branch
    atomic_store_explicit((_Atomic int*)ptr1, in1, order);
    return out1;
}
```

A non-constant `order` requires branching in the asm, or strengthening to the maximum.

We can really see the effect of over-strengthening on x86, where gcc uses `mfence` for this, but only plain `mov` for the others (which has release semantics in x86 asm).  Also in ARM32 gcc output, where we see `dmb` before *and* after the store, for seq-cst instead of just release.

```
@ gcc6.3 -Os -mcpu=cortex-m4 -mthumb
foo_variable_order:
    dmb     ish
    str     r0, [r1]
    dmb     ish             @ barrier after for seq-cst

    cmp     r0, #0
    ite     eq              @ branchless out1 = in1 ? 0 : 123
    moveq   r0, #123
    movne   r0, #0
    bx      lr
```

Comment: Thank you for this very thorough answer.    The code I'm debugging is legacy code, and is indeed much more complicated than the example I put up.   I'm fairly new to asm, and there's still a lot I'm not solid on (hence the question).   We found a bug that is likely related to the inline assembly, so I'm trying to get a better idea of the details in order to be able to understand exactly what's going on.   Your answer is very helpful in that regard.

Comment: @HardcoreHenry: It's *very* easy to write inline asm that happens to work with one compiler and one set of surrounding code, but breaks with different register allocation.  (Especially enabling link-time optimization for cross-file inlining can expose dormant problems).  Rewrite it in pure C whenever possible, especially if that doesn't hurt performance. (like this case where the compiler is able to make asm at least as nice as the question, unless that `strex` really was the closing half of an LL/SC split over multiple functions!  In which case yuck.)

Comment: @HardcoreHenry: anyway, see also the links in https://stackoverflow.com/tags/inline-assembly/info.  The bottom 2 are for ARM specifically, and most of the others apply generally.