# Why is this inline ASM function adding the first input operand twice?

Tags: c++, assembly, gcc, inline-assembly

I'm a beginner to assembly and a novice programmer in general. I'm trying to wrap my head around the basics of assembly by writing some basic inline asm functions in C++. I'm compiling with GNU g++, and the behavior is the same with every optimization setting. My PC is running windows with x86_64 architecture but inline assembly is always x86 32-bit to my understanding (is that correct? I have no formal CS/programming education so I might not know some basic things that seem obvious).

```
#include <iostream>

int sum(int a, int b, int c)
{
    int result = 0;
    asm(
        /* "addl %1, %0;" */
// The above line causes the result to be a + a + b + c.
// When commented out the result is a + b + c.
        "addl %2, %0;"
        "addl %3, %0;"
        : "=r" (result)
        : "r" (a), "r" (b), "r" (c)
    );
    return result;
}


int main()
{
    std::cout << sum(4, 10, 23) << std::endl;
// [Out] 37
}
```

My original expectation of how the above asm code was supposed to behave:

"addl %1, %0;"
--> Add the first input operand (to be assigned later) to the output operand

"addl %2, %0;"
--> Add the second input to the output

"addl %3, %0;"
--> Add the third input to the output

: "=r" (result)
--> Assign int result to be the output (%0) and store in a register (?)

: "r" (a), "r" (b), "r" (c)
--> Assign the inputs (%1, %2, %3) and store in a register (?)

chatGPT 4 insists that my original code was correct and should've resulted in a + b + c. Even when I explain the behavior of the program to chatGPT 4, it can't figure out what's happening, which is something I haven't seen before. It gave me a bunch of theories but the only one that seemed plausible was that, in plain terms, the value of the variable int a is being stored in the register that's being used to store the output, so the output is starting with the value of int a, despite int result being initialized with 0.

Can anyone help me understand what's happening?

Comment: ChatGPT is useless for assembly questions.  Hint: what is the initial value of the output operand?  What happens, when you add to it?

Comment: "despite int result being initialized with 0" -- yes but this is ignored because your inline asm says it will overwrite `result` without reading the original value (that's what the `=` constraint does), so the initial value is deemed to not matter (it does, but the compiler doesn't know that)

Comment: +1 to what @harold said, you need to use `"+r" (result)` to indicate that initial value or result must be used

Comment: @fuz I expected a to be added to 0 then b to be added to a + 0 then c to be added to a + b + 0, and then I expected int result to store that value when I used : "=r". Beyond that I don't know what you're trying to lead me to.

Comment: @harold, I still don't understand why that causes the result to be a + a + b + c instead of a + b + c when the first line of the function isn't commented out. The issue to me doesn't seem related to whether int result is read to be 0 or is overwritten (although that is good to know). I originally did not even initialize result, but tried initializing to 0 after troubleshooting (and it didnt do anything, as you might expect).

Comment: @IłyaBursov This fixed the function. Thank you! I still don't understand what's going on, but this helps me understand that "=r" was not doing what I expected.

Comment: You also need an early-clobber declaration because this function writes its RMW operand (`%0`) before the last read of any of the inputs.  [When to use earlyclobber constraint in extended GCC inline assembly?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15819794) has a similar example, but not the `mov`-immediate at the start of the template so it *is* a write-only output.  (Early-clobber problems are a lot more likely to happen in practice for pure-output than `"+r"` RMW, although picking the same register for 2 inputs is possible if the compiler knows they're the same.)

Comment: *but inline assembly is always x86 32-bit to my understanding* - MSVC specifically only supports inline asm for 32-bit x86, because its internal implementation was so clunky and brittle that they just disabled it for other ISAs instead of fixing it.  You're using a different compiler that doesn't have this limitation.  Inline asm is for the same architecture / bitness you're compiling for, so it depends on whether you're using `gcc -m32` or `gcc -m64` (or which is the default in the GCC version you installed.)

Comment: @PeterCordes Thank you! That link contains a lot of info that I didn't realize I was missing.

Comment: It adds a twice because you're not supposed to read from =r operands, so the compiler decided a register to %0 that initially holds a.

Comment: Possible duplicate [Why does my "=r"(var) output not pick the same register as "a"(var) input?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58240044) - the difference between `"=r"` and `"+r"` is the same underlying issue, but the circumstances are somewhat different.  Also [(+r) vs. (=r) constraints in GCC x86 Inline Assembly](//stackoverflow.com/q/26722008).  My answer on [inline assembly constraint for value that might be overwritten](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51938034) starts with another explanation of how to think about `"=r"`.  If any of these seem like they actually answer your Q, let me know

Comment: (This has definitely been asked before, it's just a matter of finding a close enough duplicate.  Probably most of them are going to have debugging-problem titles like this one, though, so it's hard to find them in google results for searches like `site:stackoverflow.com gcc "=r" write-only` which has a lot of hits.)

Comment: [Why can't local variable be used in GNU C basic inline asm statements?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60227941) has a good tutorial-style intro that shows using a separate output variable.

Comment: @PeterCordes Yes, those links answer my question and more importantly give me a lot more context for the basics of how inline assembly works, even though most of it is going over my head right now. Thank you for going above and beyond to provide learning resources!

Comment: @fuz Thank you. Is the fact that [a] and [result] are being assigned the same register based on the order they appear? I.e., is that predictable based on the code or is it undefined behavior?

Comment: @MAA1117 The compiler can assign registers however it pleases, and it will make use of that allowance in sufficiently complex situations (e.g. when your function is inlined).  Do not assume anything about the contents of the register allocated for an `=` constraints or what output registers it aliases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, what happens is that the expressions in the constraints are "bound" to resources as specified by the constraints, and then the asm code is emitted using the resources that were bound.  In this case (with the `"r"` constraint), all of these things are bound to registers.  An issue is that the inputs and outputs are bound independently, so a resource used for an input can be reused for an output.

So for your specific example:

: "=r" (result)
--> bind the variable `result` to a register for output (only).  So the register bound will contain the value at the end of the asm code, but not have any particular value at the start of the code.

: "r" (a), "r" (b), "r" (c)
--> bind the expressions `a`, `b`, and `c` to 3 (different) registers on input.  That means these registers will be set to have the values of these expressions prior to the asm code, but no assumptions will be made about their values after the code.

"addl %1, %0;"
--> add the register bound to `a` to the register bound to `result`

"addl %2, %0;"
--> add the register bound to `b` to the register bound to `result`

"addl %3, %0;"
--> add the register bound to `c` to the register bound to `result`

So the issue you have is that if `result` and `a` are bound to the same register (likely in such a simple case), you'll end up with a + a + b + c.  You also have the issue that if `result` is bound to a different register, that register's value (which might be anything) will be added in.

One obvious fix for both of these would be to use the constraint `"+r"` for `result` -- this binds the register to it FOR BOTH INPUT and output.  That will ensure that `result` is bound to a different register to `a`, `b`, and `c` AND that register will be 0 on entry to the asm block.

Comment: Thank you for explaining everything line by line. This gives me a much clearer picture of what specifically was going wrong and why "+r" was a solution. Do you know why [result] and [a] specifically are consistently being assigned to the same register in the original code? I was getting the answer 41 every time. Why is this result so consistent?

Comment: @MAA1117: Because you compiled with the same compiler version and options every time, with the same surrounding code for the `asm` statement, so it made the same choice of which registers were convenient for it for the inputs and output.  Once the compiler generates asm from the surrounding C, things are pretty much nailed down; you can single-step it with a debugger to see that asm and what's happening as you step on the compiler's toes in the delicate dance between the asm template string and the compiler-generated code.  (Enabling optimization will probably make a big difference.)

Comment: @PeterCordes I actually did try compiling with multiple different optimization levels, with consistent results. I also went through everything in GDB disassembly using VSCode but couldn't make sense of it. Edit: Do you have any suggestions for the best methods/software to debug asm?

Comment: @MAA1117: With nothing to bias its choices, GCC's internals often prefer to pick the same register for the first output as for the first input, with or without optimization.  The inputs here are compile-time constants with optimization enabled so this can inline.  In a `__attribute__((noipa,noinline))` version, it would want to pick the result as EAX vs. the inputs as ECX, EDX, R8D (Windows x64).

Comment: You can see a different result with gcc if you put `__attribute__((noinline))` on the sum function and compile with `-O`.  Then the choice of registers will be driven by which registers are used by the arguments and return value of the function.